# How can I decrease the numeric value of a property every time I click "confirm"?

Tags: javascript, loops, class

I would like that every time I enter the right property name "title" of my class children and confirm, the available quantity of that title (initially set to 10), decreases.

I'm going crazy, what can I do?

```
class Catalog{
    #initial = 10;
    constructor(title){
        this.title = title;
    };
    get initial(){
        return this.#initial;
    };

    set initial(value){
        return this.#initial = this.initial - value;
    };
    
    amounts(){
        let search = prompt("Cerca il tuo dvd", "");
        let confirmed = confirm("Vuoi confermare l'acquisto?");
        
        
        if(search === this.title && confirmed){
          return this.initial - 1;    // ?????????         
        } 
        
    };
    

}



class Matrix extends Catalog{
    constructor(title){
        super(title);
        this.title = title;
    };
   
    
}

const x = new Matrix("Matrix");

console.log(x.amounts())
```

Comment: `return this.initial - 1` just returns a new value which is one less then `this.initial` but it doesnt change the value of `this.initial`; You could for instance do `return --this.initial` or `this.initial -= 1; return this.initial` or `this.inital = this.initial-1; return this.initial`

Comment: And your setter for `initial` doesn't make much sense. If I do `acatalog.initial = 15`, I'd expect that the value of `acatalog.inital` is actually 15 and not depending on the prior value. If you want a method `decreaseBy` call it something like that and don't misuse the setter ...

Comment: Hi, I did this but now the value of this.initial is 10. Can you correct me by modifying the code
?